# Google Analytics UA and GA4 together with firebase Existing Project

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I am new for firebase please pardon if I don't understand something.

I have two apps running for Android and IOS and both are configured with Google Analytics UA as well as Tag manager and now I have created a new property for Analytic 4 and tag manager is there.

My firebase is linked with Universal analytics already but need to connect GA4 as well for both apps so i don't lose connecting with my universal property as well as the GA4 should also work.

Anyone here with good understanding of firebase and Analytics can help me.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find documentation to connect GA4 to Firebase here:

**[GA4] Firebase integration**. Link Google Analytics 4 properties to Firebase.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9289234?hl=en

Anyway, you don't want to worry too much about not losing the link. I have personally noticed that the old Analytics Properties for mobile always exist however Google has announced their **deletion** (except for 360):

> As of February 4th 2020, Google Analytics properties that fit the
> criteria below will have been permanently deleted. We recommend
> transitioning to measuring your apps with the Firebase SDKs.
>
> https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9167112?hl=en